# Trying to group TR rows by a common value

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have "domains". The domains own "phone numbers". What I am trying to do is group all the numbers together with their associated domain.

I'm getting lost in the logic in terms of how to know when one domain is done and another domain is now in the queue to know when to end one TR and start another so they can be grouped into their own background color or table.

My code attempt:

```
$domainsqlquery = "SELECT DOMAIN FROM phone_numbers WHERE `RESELLER_ID` ='".$RID."'";
    if ($domainresult = mysqli_query($conn, $domainsqlquery)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($domainresult) > 0) {
            while ($domainrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($domainresult)) {
                echo '<tr'.(($c = !$c)?' class="odd"':' class="even"').">";
                $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM phone_numbers WHERE `RESELLER_ID` ='".$RID."' AND `DOMAIN` ='".$domainrow['DOMAIN']."'";
                if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery)) {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<td>";
                            echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
                            echo "<input name='R_number' value='".$row['NUMBER']."' type='hidden'>";
                            echo "<input name='N_ID' value='".$row['ID']."' type='hidden'>";
                            echo $row['DOMAIN'] ." - ". $row['NUMBER'] ." - Cost: <input name='R_cost' value=".$row['COST']." style='width:50px'> <input type='submit' name='btn-drop' value='X'> &nbsp; <input type='submit' name='btn-update' value='UPDATE'> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=\"domain=".$row['DOMAIN']."&caldate=04\" target='_blank'>Open Report</a><br>";
                            echo "</form>";
                            echo "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `($c = !$c)`? You don't show where you defined `$c`, as well as you have the assignment operator `=`, so you are setting `$c` to `!$c`.

Comment: I think your tr should be inside the inner loop. Otherwise, you should have same no. of phone numbers for each of the domains. Also, you should not do your query inside your loop

Comment: Do you want one row for each domain with all the phone numbers of this domain as columns in the same row OR do you want a row for each phone number?

Comment: Each domain will have it's own row with the numbers assigned to them also in that same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest instead of looping over the results from the database and building the html, you should rather loop over the database results to create a dictionary (multi-dimensional array) of the results. I don't think you even need to query the table multiple times.

Create an array for the results:

```
$results = [];
```

With a single query, you will have an array of all the phone numbers, with the domain information in each row.

Then, loop over this array and build the `$results` array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if (!isset($results[$row['DOMAIN']])) {
    $results[$row['DOMAIN']] = [];
  }

  $results[$row['DOMAIN']][] = $row;
}
```

With this, you will have a multidimensional array of the following form:

```
[
  'DOMAIN1': [
     [], // row1 
     [], // row2 
   ],
   'DOMAIN2': [
     [],
     [],
   ],
]
```

You can now easily loop through this array, where the first level of the array will give you what domain the row is in.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was finally able to create the correct foreach statements and do as I needed. Took some time but I got it!